# Correct wheel size for a vintage Peugot

Tags: wheels

I'm currently upgrading an old Peugot frame and I'm trying to buy the correct wheel size for the bike. This is actually my second attempt after selecting the incorrect size last year. The bike is old and uses cantilever brakes and i'm trying to identify the correct width, I'm 90% confident it will accept a 700c.

The big question I'm struggling to know is the width the wheels should be. I made a massive mistake and brought 700 by 13 - ridiculously thin. I'm know hearing anything between 19 and 27 but I'm not sure what to check so I can determine the correct size.

I'm also looking for a single gear.

Any ideas what the average wheel width should be for a vintage Peugot bike?

Here are some more details on the bike:

Estimated age: 70's
Type of bike: Racer
Photos attached.

[image]

[image]

Comment: An "old Peugeot" is maybe a bit too less information to narrow down your wheel size. So give us any information you have: estimated age, type of bike (road bike, MTB, whatever), decals with names on the frame. If possible, post some photos. In its current form your question might get closed as too broad.

Comment: OK thanks, I've added more information to the question above.

Comment: Ok thanks, so it sounds like a 700c by 27 width, with the idea that some bespoke work on the hub spacing is needed. Does sound correct?

Comment: The rim size is 27" (a 630 mm rim). 700c is a 622 rim. You're probably going to have to coldset the frame to bring it up to modern hub spacing. The actual rim width will be something else, like 15 mm so you can use a decent range of tire sizes.

Comment: Looks like it uses v brakes which means you'll get a problem when attaching brakes if you use 700c tires

Comment: Those are canti posts. V-brakes weren't around until the 90s. In any case, @user15899 will likely have to take the bike to a shop to do the cold setting of the frame, and they can measure everything out there and test a few wheel+ brake combinations quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 70s Peugeot sold outside France probably used 27" wheels, not 700c wheels (though aside from the Velo Orange wheelset, you're probably going to have trouble finding 27" wheels and will have to try 700c wheels + a brake that fits it [an extra 4 mm adjustment is needed]).

The bigger issue is finding a wheel set which has hub spacing that fits this frame - likely 120mm in the back and possibly 96 mm in the front (or finding someone who is willing to cold set the frame+fork).